# Add ajax data on DataTable before send

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I initialized the DataTable in a variable:

```
var dataTable = $("#selector").DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: $.fn.dataTable.pipeline({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/path/ajaxurl",
        data: {
            "fruits": "apple",
            "veggies": "banana",
        },
        dataSrc: "data"
    }),
    sPaginationType: "extStyle"
});
```

Now, somewhere in my script I have this checkbox that when changed will add a new data on the ajax above then initialize the `draw()`:

```
$(document).on("change", "#add-some-liquors", function(e) {
    // some validations here

    // My attempt to add this data
    dataTable.data({"drinks" : "coca-cola"});

    // Draw the dataTables
    dataTable.clearPipeline().draw();
});
```

Seems that `dataTable.data({"drinks" : "coca-cola"});` does not add the drinks on the POST when I checked on the backend, I only get the apple & banana which is the two default initialized data. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

According to [the API](https://datatables.net/reference/api/) `.data` method is only for retrieving. Try holding data in a variable, updating that object and then using it in `.ajax` method.

```
var items = {}

ajax: $.fn.dataTable.pipeline({
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/path/ajaxurl",
    data: items,
```

Comment: Shouldn't it `[]` than `{}` as you suggested? Seems that I can't do a `push` on items if it is declared as `{}`?

Comment: Yeah push is for arrays. For objects you just set key and value. It shouldn't matter here which you're using.

Comment: I tried recreating data to `var testVar = [{"fruits": "apple", "veggies": "banana"}];` then place it to `data: testVar`.. now I no longer see both on the backend...

Answer (score 1):

Declare your data as a variable and add the drinks value later.

```js
var data = {
            "fruits": "apple",
            "veggies": "banana",
        };

console.log(data);

//On the click event
$('#chk').on('click', function() { 
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
     data['drinks'] = 'coca-cola';
  } else {
    //When unchecking the option, set it's value to null
    data['drinks'] = null;

    //Or delete the property.
    //delete data['drinks'];
  }

  console.log(data);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ajax.data` object can be initialized as a function. The function will be evaluated each time the data is fetched. In this example, the value of the global variable `selectedDrink` will be sent with the ajax request as the `drinks` field.

```
var selectedDrink = "";

var dataTable = $("#selector").DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: $.fn.dataTable.pipeline({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/path/ajaxurl",
        data: function(d) {
            d.fruits = "apple";
            d.veggies = "banana";
            d.drinks = selectedDrink;
        },
        dataSrc: "data"
    }),
    sPaginationType: "extStyle"
});


$(document).on("change", "#add-some-liquors", function(e) {
    selectedDrink = "coca-cola";

    // Draw the dataTables
    dataTable.clearPipeline().draw();
});
```